# Why would execution of a block of code continue past a breakpoint if you stop debugging at the breakpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a breakpoint that is a few lines before an insert into the database.  When I run the code in Visual Studio (press the play button) the breakpoint is hit.  If I click on the red "stop" button, in Visual Studio, the code execution appears to stop but apparently execution continues down to the insert because a row gets inserted into the database.

Any idea why this might happen?  If I press the stop button, the

Comment: You stopped mid-sentence.

Comment: Do you want to know why this happens or how to prevent it from happening?